# Add validation list to a UserInterfaceOnly protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have protected a worksheet using userinterfaceonly:=true. My code can then edit the protected sheet, as expected, but it bugs out when I try to add a data validation list to a cell. Is this expected behaviour? Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Unprotect the sheet. UIO is not 100% effective. In my experience it will sometimes work with DV, sometimes not.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option. The sheet must be protected.

Comment: Your code can unprotect and reprotect. It won't be as quick (especially in 2013) but it's the only real solution.